# Multiple views in a window

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF.I am working on WPF desktop app,I want that user can load multiple text file in single window and can compare them.files shown vertically and scrolling should be synchronized according to timestamp.please suggest me how to do it.the best comparison scenario is viewing multiple files in notepad++ with "Move to others view" and "verticle scrolling enabled".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a grid with two columns and add a content presenter to each column. That would allow you to display multiple views within the same window. Within those views you can display your files and synchronize the scroll position.

Something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Name="a">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="ViewOfFile1"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="ViewOfFile2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link: [How to keep two ScrollViewers in Sync in WPF](http://www.gbogea.com/2009/07/08/how-to-keep-two-scrollviewers-in-sync-in-wpf). Then you can have two `ScrollViewer`s, one for each file and keep them synchronised. This should give you functionality similar to that of notepad++.